# LINQ query on DataTable - Could not find an implementation of the query pattern

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't compile? The error is:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type `System.Data.DataTable`.  `Where` not found.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace caLINQ
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=STEVEN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=linqtest;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                 connection.Open();
                 String cmdText = "select * from customers";
                 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
                 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr;
                 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                 ds.Load(dr, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "tab1");
                 DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                 var qy = from c in dt // error is here
                          where c.country == "Italy"
                          select c.name;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be looking at using Linq2Sql instead of filling datatables and querying those.

Comment: Hi, welcome. You may consider marking one of the answers as accepted by ticking the big check mark at the left of it.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
var qy = from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
         where c.Field<string>("country") == "Italy"
         select c.Field<string>("name");
```

`AsEnumerable()` will return an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` that can be used with LINQ.

Comment: Thanks Magnus and KreepN. After implementing both your suggestions it worked. It is a trivial app that I am just using to try to get to know LINQ; I figured I would start by filling a DataTable and trying to query it. Now I can move on.

SLB

Comment: AsEnumerable() is costly

Comment: @StackOrder not on a DataTable

Answer (score 4):

Adjust your code to (I'm assuming that your DB columns are "country" and "name):

```
var qy = from DataRow c in dt.Rows
         where c.Field<string>("country") == "Italy"
         select c.Field<string>("name");
```

Or

```
var qy = (from DataRow c in dt.Rows
         where c.Field<string>("country") == "Italy"
         select c.Field<string>("name")).ToList()
```

For a list of those "names".